# Protocol 43200 after unpacking received data

Tags: python, sockets, networking, protocols, sniffer

I am trying to print information about each protocol specifically:

```
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)`
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
conn.bind((HOST, 0))
# Include IP headers
conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
# receives all packets
conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

try:
    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)
        print("Raw data received:", raw_data)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)
        print('\nEthernet Frame:')
        print(TAB_1 + 'Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(dest_mac, src_mac,     eth_proto))

        
        if eth_proto == 0x0800:
            ipv4_info = ipv4_packet(data)
            print(TAB_1 + 'IPv4 Packet:')
            print(ipv4_info)

            if proto == 1:
                icmp_details = icmp_packet(data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'ICMP Packet:')
                print(icmp_details)

            elif proto == 6:
                tcp_info = tcp_segment(data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'TCP Segment:')
                print(tcp_info)

            elif proto == 17:
                udp_details = udp_segment(data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'UDP Segment:')
                print(udp_details)
```

But, it only shows me source, destination, protocol no : 43200 and data, and no other fields.

What necessary changes should I make?

Comment: I am not sure if the function udp_segment, tcp_segment are standard library functions and have not found their documentation but I guess they takes the tcp protocol/udp protocol data only and you provide the full data including IP header.

Comment: 43200 it's 192.168. part of source address at offset=12 taken from IP header of packet that you're trying to parse, there's no ethernet header there